# Aligning, rescaling vectors, plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have two data frames, df1, and df2. Each represents a curve. Curve df1 will have two points marked on it, by design. I need to be able to do the following:

1. Make plots of each and arrange them vertically, so that they are
   evenly matched and both are perfectly square The bottom curve, df1,
   will have two points marked on it.
2. I need to be able to align the top plot (df2) such that the point
   marked on the curve matches exactly with the point on the bottom
   curve, which I illustrated by simply shifting the curve to the
   right, adding an offset value (dotted red line).
3. Also, I'd like to be able to rescale df2, so that both points marked
   on df1 could be matched with the corresponding two points on df1. This 
   would be a separate operation, optional, but still important.

What is the best way to prgorammatically rescale/shift df2 to match the points on df1? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0.04, 0.21, 0.35, 0.50, 0.66, 0.81, 0.96, 
1.11, 1.26, 1.41, 1.57, 1.70, 1.85, 2.00, 2.15, 2.31, 2.45, 2.59, 
2.74, 2.89, 3.04),y=c(1.44, 1.34, 1.26, 1.18, 1.09, 0.99, 0.89, 0.80, 
0.70, 0.60, 0.50, 0.42, 0.33, 0.25, 0.17, 0.11, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 
0.03, 0.03))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(3.0, 2.9, 2.8, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 
2.1, 2.0, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 
0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0),
              y = c(2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 2.04, 
2.03, 1.95, 1.55, 1.06, 0.72, 0.47, 0.26, 0.11, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.06, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 
0.05))

offset <- 1.4
p1 <- ggplot()+
  coord_equal(ratio=1)+
  geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=y, y=x))+
  scale_x_reverse(limits=c(4, 0))+
  scale_y_reverse(limits=c(4, 0))+
  geom_point(aes(x=1.11, y=0.62))+
  geom_point(aes(x=0.1, y=2.345))

p2 <- ggplot()+
  coord_equal(ratio=1)+
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=x+offset, y=y), linetype="dotted", 
   color="red")+
  coord_equal(ratio=1)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 4))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 4))+
  geom_point(aes(x=1.466667, y=0.1))+
  geom_point(aes(x=1.466667+offset, y=0.1))+
  geom_point(aes(x=2.0875, y=1.9))

grid.arrange(p2, p1, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, respect=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]